# issue with filterToolbar in jqGrid Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

search functionality is not working. when hitting action method in controller parameters looking like  **"_search=true", "searchField=null", "searchString=null" ,"searchOper=null",** here i am not getting values of searchField,searchString,searchOper. Please can any one help.

if i give **loadonce: true** property then search is working. but i am getting first page records only. i am not getting other page records.  How can i fix this.

**My code:**

```
$(function () {

        $("#Channelslistgrid").jqGrid({
            colNames: ['ChannelName', 'Description',  'status'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'ChannelName', index: 'ChannelName', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '200',
                            editable: false, edittype: 'text',search:true

                        },
                        { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', sortable: false, align: 'left', width: '120',
                            editable: false, edittype: 'text',search:true

                        },


                         { name: 'status', index: 'status', sortable: false, align: 'left', width: '220',
                             editable: false, edittype: 'text',search:true
                         },
                  ],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            sortname: 'Title',
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [15, 20, 25],
            sortorder: "desc",
            height: 345,
            ignoreCase: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            caption: 'Channels List',
            width: 660,
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/Channelslist")",
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            loadonce: true

        })
        jQuery("#Channelslistgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: false });

    });
```

**controller**

```
 public ActionResult Channelslist(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord, bool _search, string searchField, string searchString, string searchOper)
        {
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use the below controller code to get the search parameters typed on the filtertoolbar.

```
  public ActionResult Channelslist(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord, bool _search) {
     string ChannelName= "";
    string desc= "";
     if (Request.Params["ChannelName"] != null) ChannelName = Request.Params["ChannelName"];
     if (Request.Params["Description "] != null) desc= Request.Params["Description"];
    }
```